# C++. How to detect matching and non-matching sections with sregex_token_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

This simple code spilt the string and in `callback` function receives the tokens sequentially.

Note that the `{-1,0}` in the argument list of the iterator constructor is a list specifying the submatches we want to iterate over. The `-1` is for non-matching sections, and the `0` is for the first submatch.

```
auto callback = [&](std::string const& m) {
    std::cout << "m = " << m << std::endl;
};

std::string input_text = "my\n\t values are 9, 19";
std::regex re("are[ \\n\\t]+");
std::sregex_token_iterator
    begin(input_text.begin(), input_text.end(), re, { -1, 0 }),
    end;
std::for_each(begin, end, callback);
```

A regular expression can be anything.

`sregex_token_iterator` documentation and examples [available here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). You also can run this code on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/UKlMq1)

How do I know what case I'm working: match or non-match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not excellent, but works:

```
std::string input_text = "my\n\t values are 9, 19";
std::regex re("are[ \\n\\t]+");

auto callback = [&](std::string const& m) {
    if (std::regex_match(m, re)) {
        /* matching */
    }
    else {
        /* non-matching */
    }
};

std::sregex_token_iterator
    begin(input_text.begin(), input_text.end(), re, { -1, 0 }),
    end;
std::for_each(begin, end, callback);
```